# Simplest way to position HTML table column left

Tags: html, html-table

What is the simplest way to position a tables columns to the left?  I.e. prevent columns from justifying across the total width of the table:

Good

```
| A | B                          |
```

Bad

```
| A              | B             |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without JS (setting the first td width to content length) you would need to set the width of the first td with CSS.

Something like:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .my-table, .my-table td {
        border: 1px solid black; //border set to easily see spacing
      }
      .my-table{
        width: 500px; // initially set table width
      }
      .my-table tr td:first-child{
        width: 20px; //select first td of every row and set width
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class="my-table">
      <tr><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Would achieve what you are after. *A* would be a set width and *B* would naturally fill the rest.